# unable to get value from <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple `<input class="form-control inputDate" type="text" value="12/31/1899 7:00 PM">` on a page. I also have the following javascript,

```
var inputs = jQuery('.inputDate');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  console.log("test");
  jQuery(inputs[i]).val().split('/')[2];
  var input = jQuery(inputs[i]).val().split('/')[2];
  console.log("TEST" + input);
  if (input.length > 4) {
    input = input.split(" ")[0];
  }
  if (input < '2015') {
    jQuery(inputs[i]).val("");
  }
}
```

The problem is that `var input` does not have a value. I have tried opening up the console and testing (against the html from above) and nothing is getting the value.

I have tried,

```
jQuery(inputs[i]).val();
jQuery(inputs[0]).val();
document.getElementsByClassName("inputDate")[0].value;
```

But nothing returns the value. I think part of the issue is that the value is set in the backend to 1899 instead of starting off null.

How can I get the value?

EDIT-------------------------------------

I have done more testing and when I do

```
var test = inputs[0];
jQuery(test).val("123")
```

The HTML markup still shows the date. But if I do (from IntheWeeds)

```
jQuery(".inputDate").each(function() {
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

it returns 123 and "" even though the value in the HTML markup is still a date.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not go all the way and use the `each` method to loop your inputs?

Comment: Interesting note:  jsFiddle doesn't appear to properly support the default value of a text input.

Comment: try: $.each( $(".inputDate"), function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/nuv90Lns/

Comment: I updated the OP to add more details and explain more of the oddity I am facing.

Comment: hey your code works, but you need to make sure your javascript is set to the end of your body. in the footer will be fine.

Comment: @CayceK This code is currently set in the footer but I also can run it in the console and it does not work.

Comment: Ok... so i'm confused is it supposed to set the date value to "" IF it is less than 2015 at all??

Comment: @CayceK Thank you!! It was an order of operations issue. I was instantiating datetimepicker() before I was setting the value to be null. This caused the date to still show up as 1899. I moved that line to the end of the function and it is working as expected. Thanks!!

Comment: perfect. I was so confused because it worked exactly the way you explained, but had no datetimepicker! lol good luck in your future stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accessing the value attribute there. try

```
 var test = inputs[i];
 jQuery(test).val();
```

or use .each method:

```
var inputs = jQuery('.inputDate');
jQuery(inputs).each( 
  jQuery(this).val().split('/')[2];
  // rest of the code don't forget to get rid of ending '}'
```

Comment: I ran this code and it did not work. Just returned the null string.

Comment: Tried it and it did not work. I did more testing and updated the OP to explain what I am seeing now. Thanks!

Comment: Even though this is not the correct answer I am accepting it as an answer because of the code improvements it offers.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely would recommend using "each", as noob described in his updated answer. Here is a simplified example showing how to log each textbox value:

```
$(".inputDate").each(function() {
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var inputs = $('.inputDate').val();

// Expect: input = "12/31/1899 7:00 PM"
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work. It still returns the null string back.

Comment: do you have more than one element with the inputdate class applied?

Comment: Yes, on the specific page I am working on I have two.

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help. 
Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers.